# Add different icons for Top Posts (Q or A) to prevent confusion in the iOS app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, ios-app

There seems to be a bug in the SE app for iOS. Yesterday I've asked a question on Android Enthusiasts forum but I've found the answer myself. In the iOS app I see the same question listed twice as 'top post'.

> [image]

**Edit:**
@Patrick Hofman pointed out that this isn't a bug. However the app is lacking the icons to point out which top post is a question and which is an answer. I would like to propose his suggestion as feature request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not a bug. It shows an item for both your question and answer, just like the site does.

> [image: Screen shot]

What could help make this less ambiguous is to show the question or answer icon, just as the site does. That would be an outstanding feature request.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds plausible. I haven't noticed this before as I'm using the app most of the time. I like your suggestion about the icons and I'm going to edit the question to ask for this feature.

Comment: By the way: this is the same for the mobile website. It doesn't show an icon either.

Answer (score 5):

This will be fixed in the next build.

I'm taking the absolute simplest way out and just inserting *Q:* or *A:* in front of the title.  I'm also going to do this for question search because the web does it and the other visual cues we use are subpar.

> [image: Screenshot of top questions with Q and A in front of titles.]
>
> [image: Screenshot of search showing Q and A in front of titles.]

Comment: That sounds to me like an appropriate and clean solution. Thanks for building the new feature.